# fluentd failed loading custom parser

Tags: fluentd

fluentd fails to run with my custom parser:

my parser is named `dn_multiline_parser` and located at `lib/fluent/plugin/parser_dn_log.rb`

```
require 'fluent/plugin/parser'

# default format: "%time [%level] %message"

module Fluent
  module Plugin
    class DnLogParser < Parser
      Plugin.register_parser('dn_multiline_parser', self)
      ... (parser impl)
    end
  end
end
```

**fluentd.conf:**

```
    <worker 0>
      <source>
        @type tail
        # path /external/core/traces/*/*
        tag dn.traces
        path /core/dn_gen*
        path_key logfile
        pos_file /tmp/traces.position.traces
        tag dn.traces
        rotate_wait 5
        read_from_head true
        multiline_flush_interval 5s
        read_lines_limit 100000
        refresh_interval 1
        exclude_path ["*.gz","*.zip","*.backup"]
        <parse>
            @type dn_multiline_parser
            time_key dn_timestamp
            log_format "%t [%l] %m"
            time_length 23
            time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
        </parse>
      </source>
    </worker>
... (rest of configuration)
```

when i run fluentd, i get:

> 2019-12-23 14:32:24 +0000 [error]: config error file="/etc/fluent/fluent.conf" error_class=Fluent::ConfigError error="Unknown parser plugin 'dn_multiline_parser'. Run 'gem search -rd fluent-plugin' to find plugins"

what i've tried:

1. run fluentd with '-p /path/to/plugin_folder', and it failed with the above error
2. build a gem, install it, and run fluentd without the '-p', and it failed with the above error (my plugin exists in 'gem list' outputs)

any ideas what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Make sure your file line endings are LF if you are building for linux.

Comment: We're using Ubuntu 18.04.1 with kernel 4.15.0-23-generic.
code is written (properly, i believe) using vscode. no LF problems should occur..

Comment: Issue was fixed.
apparently, the filename should be parser_name.rb when name is the same name i"m using for registering the plugin by calling register_parser

Comment: Thanks a lot @Oded! You saved me 2 days :)